# How could viruses/malware launch from websites in user environment?

Tags: javascript, security, malware, virus, trojan

I'm familiar with web frontend only superficially.
However I'm wondering how is it possible to inject virus on the web site and cause it to run in the user environment (PC) only by visiting specific web page ? Malicious javascript, some kind of exploits, etc. ?
AFAIK, browser shouldn't allow to run .exe files on user's environment. Any thoughts ?